# Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, *[id="name-form"]) - ng e2e

Tags: angular, e2e-testing

performing tests with the command:

`ng e2e --port 4200`

in the console returns me an error:
`- Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, *[id="login-form"])`

my script:

**app.e2e-spec.ts**

```
import { AppPage } from './app.po';
import {browser, by, element} from 'protractor';

describe('nameProject App', () => {
  let page: AppPage;

  beforeAll(() => {
    page = new AppPage();
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    page.navigateTo();
    const formLogin = page.showFormLogin();

    const login = page.fillFormAndSendLogin(formLogin);

    browser.sleep(19000);
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true); 
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
  });

  it('should display welcome message', () => {
  });

});
```

**app.po.ts:**

```
import { browser, by, element } from 'protractor';

export class AppPage {
  navigateTo() {
    return browser.get('/user/login');
  }

  fillFormAndSendLogin(form) {
    const user_data_login_password = 'www';     form.element(by.css('input[name=userName]')).sendKeys(user_data_login_password);
    form.element(by.css('input[name=password]')).sendKeys(user_data_login_password);

    form.element(by.buttonText('Login')).click();
    return user_data_login_password;
  }

  getLoginBtn() {
    return element(by.buttonText('Login'));
  }

  getFormLogin() {
    return element(by.id('login-form'));
  }

  click_login() {

    const btnLoginItem = this.getLoginBtn();
    btnLoginItem.click();
  }

  showFormLogin() {
    return this.getFormLogin();
  }

}
```

Login works as I have a running server and I will execute the `ng build` command

**login form:**

```
    <div class="panel-body">
        <form id='login-form' class="example-form" [formGroup]="loginForm" >

            <label for="name">Name user *</label>
            <input required type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="userName" name ="userName" required>     

            <label for="name">Password *</label>
            <input required type="password" class="form-control"  formControlName="password" name ="password" required> 

            <button type="submit" (click)="login()" class="btn btn-success" id="Login" title="Login">Login</button>        
        </form>
    </div>
```

I use the MongoDB database. MongoDB database works on `localhost:4200`. The app also works on `localhost:4200`.

in a browser, it displays this message to me:

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'd:\name-project\dist\index.html'`

I do not know how to fix this error.

Comment: Do you have a condition around your form ? I mean a `*ngIf`

Comment: I do not use `*ngIf` on this form

Comment: in a browser, it displays this message to me:

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'd:\name-project\dist\index.html'`

Comment: So your issue is post-build ?

Comment: in consol: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
login Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`  but how to run applications by the command `ng build` this login works

Comment: I Don't understand you. What is your issue, a unit test issue or a post-production issue ? Be very clear please.

Comment: I wanted to test the user's login. I want to enter the test data `form.element(by.css('input[name=userName]')).sendKeys(user_data_login_password);` and click the button `form.element(by.buttonText('Login')).click();` Then I want to see if the page is redirecting correctly to`localhost:4200` but in the browser during the tests. An error is displayed: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
login Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: how to run tests the `dist` directory is removed

Answer (score 0):

the command helped:
`ng e2e --delete-output-path=false`